# How to use fitted values after testing on stationarity

Tags: r, ardl

community,

I am not that experienced in using R but I am currently working on an ARDL-modell to predict short- and long-run elasticities. For this, I also checked all my variables for stationarity, as ARDL requires variables that are integrated of order I(0) or I(1).

For every variable, I figured out which assumption fits best (e.g. trend, drift, etc.) while testing for stationarity. However, I don't know how to include these "best-fitted" values in my ARDL-model afterwards. For example, for one variable it turned out that it's trend and drift stationary in its first difference. How do I proceed with that?

Many thanks in advance!

I couldn't find "fitted values" in the ADF-Tests or anything comparable which I could use afterwards.